# How to fix incomplete pattern matching in agda

Tags: functional-programming, agda

Here's the code from a custom agda library. In the following code,  stands for vector and ℕ for Natural numbers. The take type is similar to that of Haskell. Example: "take 3 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]" results in [1,2,3].

```
take : ∀{A : Set}{n : ℕ} → (m : ℕ) →  A n →  A m
take 0 xs = []
take (suc m) (x :: xs) = x :: take m xs
```

I keep getting the error:

> Incomplete pattern matching for take. Missing cases:
>          take (suc
>   m) [] when checking the definition of take

I dont understand, what possible proof I might be missing out.

Answer (score 2):

The type signature of `take` says that for any completely unconstrained `m` you can return a `Vec` of length `m` having a `Vec` of length `n`. This is not true of course as `m` must be less or equal to `n`, because you want to return a prefix of a `Vec`. And since a number of elements to take and the length of a `Vec` are unrelated to each other, Agda gives you that error about incomplete pattern matching.

In Agda standard library the restriction that `m` is less or equal to the length of an input `Vec` is expressed as follows:

```
take : ∀ {a} {A : Set a} m {n} → Vec A (m + n) → Vec A m
```

You can also define something like

```
take : ∀ {a} {A : Set a} {m n} → m ≤ n → Vec A n → Vec A m
```

Or even

```
take : ∀ {a} {A : Set a} m {n} → Vec A n → Vec A (m ⊔ n)
```

to model the behavior of `Data.List.take` (where `_⊔_` means `min` in Agda stdlib).

Answer (score 1):

You are pattern-matching on `m` and a vector `xs` of type  `A n`. There is no guarantee that, because `m` is `suc`-headed that `xs` is non-empty. As the error suggests, you need to also consider the case where `m` is a `suc` and `xs` is empty.

Alternatively, you can write a function with a more precise type guaranteeing the fact that `xs` is at least as long as `m`. This is what is used in the standard library:

```
take : ∀ {A : Set} m {n} → Vec A (m + n) → Vec A m
```